# How do I use the Stimulsoft date functions

Tags: json, stimulsoft

I am using the StimulsoftJS designer and adding a Group header.  The grouping condition is based on a date which comes from my json object as a string.   How can format it into a date so I can use WeekOFYear?   Since the date is in a string format in the json and I dont see a tryParseToDate function, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to this is to edit the data source in the designer and select the datatype as DATETIME.